# <h:outputtext> Tag Library supports namespace: http://java.sun.com/jsf/html, but no tag was defined for name: outputtext

Tags: java, jsf

Using JSF 2.2, Jboss 7. While running its just keep getting " Tag Library supports namespace: http://java.sun.com/jsf/html, but no tag was defined for name: outputtext" this error.. Anyone help me to solve this problem..

Below is that xhtml file. the error is on "" this line.

index.xhtml:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE composition PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
    xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"
    template="template/ui.xhtml">
<ui:define name="body">
    <h3>Welcome to JSF Lab</h3>
    <h4>Pure JSF</h4>

    <p>
      <!-- Shows the error or success message -->
      <h:outputtext value="#{fileUploadMBean.message}" 
        rendered="#{!empty fileUploadMBean.message}">
      </h:outputtext>
      <!-- notice the enctype for file upload -->
      <h:form prependid="false" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <h:panelgrid>
      <!-- input for files -->
      <h:inputfile value="#{fileUploadMBean.file1}"></h:inputfile>
                    <h:inputfile value="#{fileUploadMBean.file2}"/>
      <!-- action which is responsible for uploading file(s) -->
      <h:commandbutton action="#{fileUploadMBean.uploadFile()}" value="Upload" />
      </h:panelgrid>
      </h:form>
    </p>
      </ui:define>
      </ui:composition>
```

This is the bean file for above xml file.. this

```
FileUploadMBean.java

@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class FileUploadMBean implements Serializable {
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
  private Part file1;
  private Part file2;
  private String message;
  public Part getFile1() {
    return file1;
  }
  public void setFile1(Part file1) {
    this.file1 = file1;
  }
  public Part getFile2() {
    return file2;
  }
  public void setFile2(Part file2) {
    this.file2 = file2;
  }
  public String getMessage() {
    return message;
  }
  public void setMessage(String message) {
    this.message = message;
  }
  public String uploadFile() throws IOException {
    //upload code
  }
}
```

I know the libraries and versions are okay. because when i run another bean class with another xhtml its working fine that same h:outputtext is showing no error.. the problem i am not understanding. is it would be any configuration issue or something else.

Comment: This is a simple typo. Java and XML are case sensitive (like conversational English, by the way; you seem to be consistently failing to firmly press the Shift key at the right moments, not only in code but also in English). Please take a good cup of coffee and exactly follow the examples and documentation and pay a bit more love and attention to the Shift key. The compiler and the humanhood will be thankful.

Comment: No solution yet.. May i know the reson its downvoted...

Comment: Hi BalusC.the above problem is cleared. now, i am getting "<h:inputFile> Tag Library supports namespace: java.sun.com/jsf/html, but no tag was defined for name: inputFile". eventhough i use jsf 2.2 . i could not find the solution for this. help me.

Comment: Then you don't have JSF 2.2 in build path. This is a different problem than currently asked.

Comment: i am running in Maven. so all jsf libraries are configured and except <h:inputFile> tag all other tags are working. now where i am missing. is that the problem in buildpath.

Answer (score 0):

As Balus C says in comment its typo mistake

Use

```
<h:outputText> </h:outputText>
<h:panelGrid></h:panelGrid>
<h:commandButton action="#{fileUploadMBean.uploadFile}" value="Upload" ></h:commandButton>
```

Comment: Hi.the above problem is cleared. now, i am getting "<h:inputFile> Tag Library supports namespace: http://java.sun.com/jsf/html, but no tag was defined for name: inputFile". eventhough i use jsf 2.2 . i could not find the solution for this. help me.